# Azure devops deleted release-X

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, azure-devops

I accidentally deleted release-X from a specific release.

Is there a way to restore it? It's important for historical audits.
by powershell script with PAT or something like that

For example, I have released Service 1#, but I mistakenly deleted Release 233, and now I want to restore it.

I tried some powershell scripts from doc microsoft

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to restore it? It's important for historical audits. by powershell script with PAT or something like that

Yes. You can refer to the following steps to restore the deleted release record.

Step1: Open Release **Filter** and select the **Deleted** status.

[image]

Step2: Use **Undelete** option to restore the release record.

[image]

To use the Rest APIs to restore the release records, you can use the following rest api:

1.Use Rest API to get the deleted release: [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```
Get https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={definitionid}&isDeleted=true&api-version=7.1-preview.8
```

2.Use Rest API to restore the deleted release: [Releases - Update Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```
Put https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseID}?comment=test&api-version=6.0-preview.8
```

PowerShell example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={releasedefinitionid}&isDeleted=true&api-version=7.1-preview.8"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

foreach($releaseid in $response.value.id)
{
   echo $releaseid
   $url1="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/Release/releases/$($releaseid)?comment=test&api-version=6.0-preview.8"


   $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT  -ContentType application/json
}
```